# How do you autovivify arrays in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Suppose I'm iterating over data and building up a multi-dimensional array. Inside the loop I want to do:

```
arr[x][y].push(z);
```

But if it's the first time a particular value has been seen for `x` or `y` then the array doesn't exist yet.

Is there an idiom in JS for doing this?

EDIT: Edited to make it clear this is about arrays, not objects.

Comment: No, sorry. PHP will do it, JS has nothing automatic.

Comment: You can use conditional chaining when reading a nested value if the intermediates might not exist, but there's nothing similar for creating.

Comment: Note that unless `cake` and `ingredient` are numbers, you likely want to be using an object for `arr` than an array...

Comment: @Barmar `((arr ??= [])[cake] ??= [])[ingredient] = quantity;` (or if they're not numeric indices, `((arr ??= {})[cake] ??= {})[ingredient] = quantity;`)

Comment: @Bergi Ugh! Remember when they complained Perl was a write-only language?

Comment: Bad example, sorry - they are indeed numbers.

Comment: `arr[x] ??= []` seems ok for one level of nesting, but how does it work for more?

Comment: @joachim The expression returns the array, so you can nest it: `(((…)[x] ??= [])[y] ??= []).push(z)`